# Classic ASP.NET Delete event is not invoked in dynamically generated datagrid control delete link

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, datagridview, dopostback

I have a classic asp.net application.  I have a datagrid user control with the MarkUp data source as:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource" runat="server" DeleteCommand="UPDATE tblLSystem SET LS_Deleted='1' WHERE LS_ID=@LS_ID"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM vwLSystem WHERE LS_Deleted='0' order by LS_CreatedOn" OnSelected="DataSource_Selected" OnDeleted="DataSource_Selected" OnDeleting = "DataSource_Deleting">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="LS_ID" Type="Object" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The delete linkbutton template is declared as:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="" Visible="True"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>            
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The code behind class name is "class StudLSystemGrid".  And the DataSource_Deleting event function in this class is:

```
protected void DataSource_Deleting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
}
```

This user control is used in another asp.net page.  It is registered in the page as:

```
<%@ Register Src="Controls/LSystemGrid.ascx" TagName="LSystemGrid" TagPrefix="uc4" %>
```

In the same page it is used to create one user control statically like this:

```
  <uc4:LSystemGrid ID="LSystemGrid1" runat="server" ShowAuditFields="false" />
```

I also need to create multiple user controls depending on the situation dynamically in code behind.  So I have a placeholder in MarkUp page:

```
  <asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>
```

And same codes in code behind to generate the user control:

```
    ucLControl =
      LoadControl("Controls/LSystemGrid.ascx")
      as StudLSystemGrid;
    ucLControl.ID = "LSystemGridPD" + i.ToString();
    ucLControl.ShowAuditFields = false;
    ucLControl.SqlDataSource.ConnectionString = ConnectionManager.ConnectionString;
    ucLControl.DataBind();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ucLControl);
```

The statically generated user control works fine.  Clicking the delete link can invoke the function "DataSource_Deleting" mentioned earlier.  However the dynamically generated user control does not work.  The function "DataSource_Deleting" is not hit and the item can not be deleted.

The html source for the delete link in statically markup user control is:

```
       <a onclick="{alert('There'); return false;} ;" 
id="ctl00_PageBody_LSystemGrid1_BaseGrid_ctl02_btnDelete" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageBody$LSystemGrid1$BaseGrid$ctl02$btnDelete','')">Delete</a>
```

For dynamically generated user control from code behind is:

```
       <a onclick="{alert('Here'); return false;} ;" 
id="LSystemGridPD0_BaseGrid_ctl13_btnDelete" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack('LSystemGridPD0$BaseGrid$ctl13$btnDelete','')">Delete</a>
```

Anybody knows what is wrong here?  How can we determine the datagrid is in delete mode when using delete linkbutton in this way in code behind?

Thanks

Update:  The user control is dynamically generated from -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PreRender += LSystem_PreRender;    
}

void LSystem_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ucLControl =
      LoadControl("Controls/LSystemGrid.ascx")
      as StudLSystemGrid;
    ucLControl.ID = "LSystemGridPD0";
    ucLControl.ShowAuditFields = false;
    ucLControl.SqlDataSource.ConnectionString = ConnectionManager.ConnectionString;
    ucLControl.DataBind();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ucLControl);
}
```

Update 2:

Update 2:  The user control is dynamically generated from -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ucLControl =
      LoadControl("Controls/LSystemGrid.ascx")
      as StudLSystemGrid;
    ucLControl.ID = "LSystemGridPD0";
    ucLControl.ShowAuditFields = false;
    ucLControl.SqlDataSource.ConnectionString = ConnectionManager.ConnectionString;
    ucLControl.EnableViewState = true;
    ucLControl.DataBind();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ucLControl);
}
```

Comment: In what moment are you creating the control dynamically? In what page event?

Comment: @Mt. Schneiders, when in page load event, the control is created.  Thanks

Comment: Can you update with all the page load code?

Comment: @Mt. Schneiders, I updated with a simplified codes to show the logic.

Comment: Try creating the control on Page Load instead of in the PreRender Event.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders, Sorry it still does not work like Update 2.  I enable the view state there also.

Comment: Try removing the `{alert('There'); return false;} ;` part on the LinkButton.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders, I removed the alert but it does not make any difference.  It still does not work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43956/discussion-between-mt-schneiders-and-don)

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders, thanks for your help.  It is very valuable for me to find the problem.  I have posted the solution in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem.  Data has been bound after

```
   ucLControl = LoadControl("Controls/LSystemGrid.ascx")       as StudLSystemGrid;
```

Invoking ucLControl.DataBind(); again wipes out the bounded attributes.

After removed the line "ucLControl.DataBind();", the delete event can be triggered.