# Pass ASP:LinkButton CommandArgument to __doPostBack __EVENTARGUMENT

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dopostback, asplinkbutton, commandargument

In ASP.NET linkbutton -

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" SortExpression="" Visible="True"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text="Delete"/>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Will __doPostBack function always be generated?  If so, how can I overwrite it and manually pass the CommandArgument to __EVENTARGUMENT?  By default __EVENTARGUMENT seems to be empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CommandArgument`, as well as the `CommandName` are not sent from the client side to the server. They are Stored on the LinkButton's Viewstate and retrieved on the server side. In this case, the `__EVENTARGUMENT` Form Key will be empty.

You should be able to access the CommandArgument on the `OnRowCommand` event of the `GridView`

Comment: you answered this question.  Thanks.  The problem is that my control can not generate OnRowCommand event.  I don't know why.  This question is a sub question of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779650/classic-asp-net-delete-event-is-not-invoked-in-dynamically-generated-datagrid-co".  Could you please take a look at that one too?