# Should I use HtmlEncode on CommandArgument?

Tags: webforms, xss

I know I must use HtmlEncode() on everything that's displayed (Labels, etc.)

Do I also need to use it in my data-bound buttons' `CommandArgument` ? (even though I can't, on input, trust them to still be so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20791870/1455631

> The `CommandArgument`, as well as the `CommandName` are not sent from the client side to the server. They are Stored on the LinkButton's Viewstate and retrieved on the server side. In this case, the `__EVENTARGUMENT` Form Key will be empty.

Which means, there's no need to sanitize `CommandArgument`.